# Linux font that similar to windows 2016 core cmd's font

Tags: linux, windows, fonts

[image]

I have this windows 2016 core cmd font, as picture above. I want to know how to use similar font on X11 windowing system — Arch linux.

Do you know what font would give similar appearance?

Comment: Can you tell us which distro, and if you want the font for use in the windowing system? (Linux is just the kernel, you are probably asking about Gnu and X11). What aspect of the font do you want (Fixed width, seriffed, exact match)?

Comment: You still have not told us what it is about the font that you want. An exact copy would be a copyright violation. But if you tell us what your goal is, then maybe we can find a font.

Comment: Sminilar font I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This font used by Microsoft is called Consolas, and it's **not** free.
There is a font called [Inconsolata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconsolata) which looks a lot like Consolas. Inconsolata is an Open Font License font so you should definitely be able to install it on your GNU/Linux system - the specifics of how to intall it depend on your actual distribution.